# hybris datahub caches CanonicalItem datas

Tags: caching, idoc, hybris-data-hub

I implemented a new extension for datahub to process DEBMAS IDOC's. This are the relevant part of my implementation:

```
<!-- raw.xml -->
<type>CanonicalParty</type>
    <attributes>
        ....
        <attribute>
            <name>addresses</name>
            <transformations>
                <transformation>
                    <rawSource>RawDEBMASU</rawSource>
                    <expression spel="true">T(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils).stripStart(getField("E1KNA1M-KUNNR"),"0")
                        + '|' + T(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils).stripStart(getField("E1KNA1M-E1KNVVM-E1KNVPM-KUNN2"),"0")
                        + '|' + 'KNA1' + '|' + getField("E1KNA1M-E1KNVVM-E1KNVPM-PARVW")</expression>
                </transformation>
            </transformations>
        </attribute>
        ...
    </attributes>
</item>

<!-- canonical.xml -->
<canonicalItems>
    <item>
        <type>CanonicalParty</type>
        <attributes>
            ...
            <attribute>
                <name>addresses</name>
                <model>
                    <localizable>false</localizable>
                    <collection>true</collection>
                    <type>String</type>
                    <primaryKey>false</primaryKey>
                </model>
            </attribute>
            ...
        </attributes>
    </item>
</canonicalItems>

<!-- target.xml -->
<targetItems>
    <item>
        <type>Company</type>
        <exportCode>B2BUnit</exportCode>
        <description>Company</description>
        <updatable>true</updatable>
        <canonicalItemSource>CanonicalParty</canonicalItemSource>
        <status></status>
        <attributes>
            ...
            <attribute>
                <name>addresses</name>
                <localizable>false</localizable>
                <collection>true</collection>
                <transformationExpression>addresses</transformationExpression>
                <exportCode>addresses(publicKey)[cellDecorator=ch.vzug.internet.imports.datahub.decorator.VzugAddressRemoveDecorator][mode=replace]</exportCode>
                <mandatoryInHeader>false</mandatoryInHeader>
            </attribute>
            ...
        </attributes>
    </item>
</targetItems>
```

When I receive the following IDOC it is processed correctly, creating 4 addresses:

```
<!-- Example IDOC -->
<ZDEBMASENH1>
    <IDOC BEGIN="1">
    ...
    <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
        <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
        <PARVW>AG</PARVW>
        <KUNN2>0010022191</KUNN2>
        <PARZA>000</PARZA>
        <Z1E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
            ...
        </Z1E1KNVPM>
    </E1KNVPM>
    <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
        <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
        <PARVW>RE</PARVW>
        <KUNN2>0010022191</KUNN2>
        <PARZA>000</PARZA>
        <Z1E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
            ...
        </Z1E1KNVPM>
    </E1KNVPM>
    <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
        <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
        <PARVW>WE</PARVW>
        <KUNN2>0015000461</KUNN2>
        <DEFPA>X</DEFPA>
        <PARZA>000</PARZA>
        <Z1E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
            ...
        </Z1E1KNVPM>
    </E1KNVPM>
    <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
        <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
        <PARVW>WE</PARVW>
        <KUNN2>0015000500</KUNN2>
        <DEFPA>X</DEFPA>
        <PARZA>000</PARZA>
        <Z1E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
            ...
        </Z1E1KNVPM>
    </E1KNVPM>
    ...
    </IDOC>
</ZDEBMASENH1>
```

When one address is deleted in SAP, I will receive the same IDOC containing only 3 addresses. The existing 3 address object are created correctly in hybris according to the IDOC, but the relation (field "addresses") still contains 4 addresses. Therefore, my decorator believes, there are still 4 addresses and the deleted one will not be deleted in hybris. I believe this information comes from a cache.

Here are the related CanonicalItem. Both are created during deletion process.

------ Correct CanonicalItem, not published ------

```
<itemData>
<type>CanonicalParty</type>
<dataPool>SAPCUSTOMER_INBOUND_POOL</dataPool>
<id>19</id>
<attribute>
<name>compositionAction</name>
<values>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">2</value>
</values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>integrationKey</name>
<values>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">10022191</value>
</values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>rawItems</name>
<values>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:long">7</value>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:long">9</value>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:long">11</value>
</values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>publicationStatuses</name>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>status</name>
<values>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">ARCHIVED</value>
</values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>lastName</name>
<values>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">TestName</value>
</values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>parent</name>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>addresses</name>
<values>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">10022191|15000461|KNA1|WE</value>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">10022191|10022191|KNA1|RE</value>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">10022191|10022191|KNA1|AG</value>
</values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>communicationLanguage</name>
<values>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">DE</value>
</values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>role</name>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>gender</name>
<values>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">2</value>
</values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>accountGroup</name>
<values>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">YA00</value>
</values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>dateOfBirth</name>
<values>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">00000000</value>
</values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>title</name>
<values>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">0003</value>
</values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>type</name>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>customerCountry</name>
<values>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">CH</value>
</values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>firstName</name>
<values>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">Peter</value>
</values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>externalPartyId</name>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>function</name>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>name</name>
<values>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">TestCompany Name</value>
</values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>partyId</name>
<values>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">10022191</value>
</values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>department</name>
</attribute>
<link rel="RawItemSource" href="http://localhost:8080/datahub-webapp/v1/raw-items/7"/>
<link rel="RawItemSource" href="http://localhost:8080/datahub-webapp/v1/raw-items/9"/>
<link rel="RawItemSource" href="http://localhost:8080/datahub-webapp/v1/raw-items/11"/>
</itemData>
```

------ Wrong CanonicalItem but published successfully ------

```
<itemData>
<type>CanonicalParty</type>
<dataPool>SAPCUSTOMER_INBOUND_POOL</dataPool>
<id>18</id>
<attribute>
<name>compositionAction</name>
<values>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">2</value>
</values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>integrationKey</name>
<values>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">10022191</value>
</values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>rawItems</name>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>publicationStatuses</name>
<values>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="canonicalItemPublicationStatusData">
<targetSystemPublicationId>5</targetSystemPublicationId>
<targetSystemName>HybrisCore</targetSystemName>
<type>CanonicalParty</type>
<canonicalItemId>18</canonicalItemId>
<integrationKey>10022191</integrationKey>
<status>SUCCESS</status>
</value>
</values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>status</name>
<values>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">SUCCESS</value>
</values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>lastName</name>
<values>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">TestName</value>
</values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>parent</name>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>addresses</name>
<values>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">10022191|15000461|KNA1|WE</value>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">10022191|10022191|KNA1|RE</value>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">10022191|10022191|KNA1|AG</value>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">10022191|15000502|KNA1|WE</value>
</values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>communicationLanguage</name>
<values>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">DE</value>
</values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>role</name>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>gender</name>
<values>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">2</value>
</values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>accountGroup</name>
<values>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">YA00</value>
</values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>dateOfBirth</name>
<values>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">00000000</value>
</values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>title</name>
<values>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">0003</value>
</values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>type</name>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>customerCountry</name>
<values>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">CH</value>
</values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>firstName</name>
<values>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">Peter</value>
</values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>externalPartyId</name>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>function</name>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>name</name>
<values>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">TestCompany Name</value>
</values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>partyId</name>
<values>
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">10022191</value>
</values>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>department</name>
</attribute>
</itemData>
```

Does anyone has an idea how to solve that issue?
Thanks in advance

Andy

Answer (score 0):

The Canonical item is regulated by the Collections framework in java. Within the collections the items are noted and therefore your 4 items are expected what you have drawn as cache. Initialize the collection in the appropriate Java code once to see what happens.